# Ways to confront users with ad blockers?

Tags: adblock

I know it's common to display banners to such users asking them to turn adblock off, however, I am wondering if there is

- a tool that nevertheless circumvent the issue so that my ads are shown
- an ad network which provide ads not blocked by ad blockers?

Comment: You can make a message that says "If you want to enter my site, turn off your ad block" then live with the fact that your traffic dies. Or you can try to constantly skoot around the blocks, which would annoy enough people that your traffic dies too. Or....just realize the age of banner success is over and people are sick of the spammy crap plastered over everything in sight. Personally im glad there is no way for you to bypass block to force ads down our throats :)

Comment: Head of the list, keep your website secure and don't serve out objectionable ads. Got tired of the antivirus scan going off on certain sites due to either badly managed WordPress installations or malware bearing advertisements. Simple method, have an underlay that shows when ads are blocked containing a diplomatic message explaining your website depends on advertising to stay afloat. Being forced to accept malware redirect ads will guarantee that I will blacklist your website and never view it again.

Answer (score 2):

The long and short of it is no, to both of your questions.

> Is there an ad network which provide ads not blocked by ad blockers?

No, at least not a reliable long-term one. As advertising networks appear, soon enough people see the adverts and report them so they would get blocked. You would be fighting a war of attrition with your users ad-blockers that probably wouldn't reflect well on you, and you'd have to keep switching ad providers which limits your choice and you'd probably not get enough clicks from one before it was blocked to meet their payout threshold.

> Is there a tool that nevertheless circumvent the issue so that my ads are shown?

If there were tools to circumvent the blockers, the use of such software wouldn't be as popular as it clearly is. Your best chance of getting your adverts displayed is to get onto the white-lists maintained by owners of the ad-blocking software, and hope your users keep the default settings (which allow non-intrusive ads). Or, providing a sense of community and regular user base who trust you not to bombard them with crap. Some users actually do disable ad-blocking if they like a site, and it asks them nicely.

The last time I checked, the most used ad-blocking software was AdBlock Plus. They provide details on [their pages](https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads) of how to submit your site for consideration to be white-listed. Doing so you must meet their criteria of what they consider "not intrusive".